# WordPress Event Espresso 4 Decaf plugin. Multiple attendee registration

Tags: wordpress

I am using the free version of the WordPress Event Espresso 4 Decaf plugin. It is only asking for one Attendee registration while the user is selecting more than one attendee. I want to modify that plugin and get all attendees' registration. How do I do it?

Comment: This question appears to be too broad, it would help to know what solutions you have tried, and what your knowledge level is on the components of the solution. For example, let us know how much PHP, wordpress, SQL, JavaScript, and HTML knowledge you already have. Because you may need to cover the basic knowledge before delving into building the plugin.

Comment: I ma 3 years experience in PHP, MySQL JavaScript, and HTML. I just want to display multi attendee info and submit into database.